# Why is $\min(X_1, ..., X_n)$ Markov chain?

Tags: markov-process

Why is $\min(X_1, ..., X_n)$ of id $X_i: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ a Markov chain?

Answer (score 7):

Hint, define : $A_{n}=\min(X_1,...,X_n)$ and observe that :

$$A_{n+1}=\min(X_1,...,X_n,X_{n+1})=\min(A_n,X_{n+1})$$

Comment: So then if one considers whether $P(A_n = s_n | A_{n-1} = s_{n-1}, ..., A_1 = s_1)=P(A_n = s_n | A_{n-1} = s_{n-1})$?

Comment: That is the lack of memory property of a Markov process.  The future value of the variable depends only on the previous value and not on the rest of the past.

Comment: @MichaelChernick But shouldn't the property be proved in order to prove that this is a Markov chain?